# WordPress 5.9 error: access-denied - on all themes - methods to debug this?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, wordpress

i am facing a fancy error on a WP 5.9 that runs with a set of plugins. lastly i ve added a theme called jobscout - that works with Wp-job-manager. During the customization i run into the access-denied-error (see demo-pages below).

**setup**: the page is configured as Static-Page and Post-Page.
its a BETA-page with the following plugins.

Site - WP Version: 5.9
MySQL version 5.5.33
php_version: 7.4.11 64bit

- wp-job-manager;
- participants-db;
- polylang (since i wanted to run the page in 5 languages - but nowadays i prefer only one lang; plain english)
- Restricted-Site-Access: for temp. switch off of the page for maintenance
- last week i ve added the Theme Jobscout see https://rarathemes.com/

i have customized the page & the site /(which runs in BETA) and suddenly i run into the error "access denied" i get it on the pages which are not combined with any plugin -

- see impressum ( page-policy: https://www.job-starter.com/impressum/ )
- die dsgvo (gdbr: https://www.job-starter.com/impressum/ )
- post  a job-seite  https://www.job-starter.com/post-a-job/
- job dashboard: https://www.job-starter.com/job-dashboard/
- https://www.job-starter.com/job/backend-software-engineer-python-django-at-brisbane-hospital/

see below the site-log files and the data of the site-health:

Question: i am facing this error on allmost every page: access-denied - on all themes -
any methods to debug this ?

see more data regarding site-health and errorlog: https://filebin.net/tjexvvozdh8juo25/the_upload_errorllog_.txt

the Errorlog:

```
WordPress database error Table 'jc.wp_pmxi_imports' doesn't exist for query SELECT options FROM wp_pmxi_imports WHERE id = 0 made by require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WPAI_WP_Job_Manager_Add_On->init, WPAI_WP_Job_Manager_Add_On_Helper->get_post_type, referer: https://www.my_site.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=27&action=edit
WordPress database error Table 'jc.wp_pmxi_imports' doesn't exist for query SELECT options FROM wp_pmxi_imports WHERE id = 0 made by require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WPAI_WP_Job_Manager_Add_On->init, WPAI_WP_Job_Manager_Add_On_Helper->get_post_type, referer: https://www.my_site.com/wp-admin/themes.php
WordPress database error Table 'jc.wp_pmxi_imports' doesn't exist for query SELECT options FROM wp_pmxi_imports WHERE id = 0 made by require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WPAI_WP_Job_Manager_Add_On->init, WPAI_WP_Job_Manager_Add_On_Helper->get_post_type, referer: https://www.my_site.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=27&action=edit
[Mon Feb 14 10:07:25.031466 2022] [core:error] [pid 5964]
```

**update:** See the additonal bug-notification from the system what i get when editing a posting:

```
 Deprecated: block_editor_preload_paths is deprecated since version 5.8.0!
Use block_editor_rest_api_preload_paths instead in /sites/job-starter.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5691
```

@nbk pointed me to the manpages that mention the correct installation-process. Well this is food for thought.

i guess that he hit the point: In other words: Well - this is a follow-up update: this means i have installed the new version 5.9 over the old version - which has had lots of plugins and fancy stuff. This quick and dirty upgrade is probably not the appropiated way and mehtod. Note: nonetheless i did not run into any trouble in the last two weeks: All was nice. even the db-update that was processed imitiatly afer the installation - all went smoothly. But honestly:I think that i do a fresh install from ground up tomorrow –

@nbk - you encourage me to do a fresh installation tomorrow. I am pretty sure that i get rid of all the fancy behaviour. - with this i leave all the language overhead (postings and pages ni allmost 5 languages - and additonally a polylang ) which makes the whole system much more complex and tricky to handle. I guess that the fresh and clean install is the best method to get everything under controll - Thanks for you - pointing to this important thing.

**update II:** i have encontered in the site health status a interesting message: see https://www.my-page.com/wp-admin/site-health.php

```
The REST API encountered an unexpected result
Performance
The REST API is one way WordPress, and other applications, communicate with the server. One example is the block editor screen, which relies on this to display, and save, your posts and pages.
The REST API call gave the following unexpected result: (403) <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>403 Forbidden</title> </head><body> <h1>Forbidden</h1> <p>You don't have permission to access this resource.Reason: The client software did not provide a hostname using Server Name Indication (SNI), which is required to access this server.<br /> </p> </body></html> .
```

this is very interesting

Comment: Did you follow all instructions on https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/ especially those which concern the database

Comment: good day dear @nbk ;many thanks for the quick reply. Glad to hear from you. Guess that you hit the point. In other words: Well - this is a follow-up update: this means i have installed the new version 5.9 over the old version - which has had lots of plugins and fancy stuff. This quick and dirty upgrade is probably not the appropiated way and mehtod. Note: nonetheless i did not run into any trouble in the last two weeks: All was nice.  even the db-update that was processed imitiatly afer the installation - all went smoothly. But honestly:I think that i do a fresh install from ground up tomorrow

Comment: @nbk: many thanks for the hint - you encourage me to do a fresh installation tomorrow. 
I am pretty sure that i get rid of all the fancy behaviour. - with this i leave all the language overhead (postings and pages ni allmost 5 languages - and additonally a polylang ) which makes the whole system much more complex and tricky to handle. 
I guess that the fresh and clean install is the best method to get everything under controll - Thanks for you - pointing to this important thing.  I am glad to be here in this great forum. Have a great day.

Comment: See the additonal bug-notification from the system what i get when editing a posting: Deprecated: block_editor_preload_paths is deprecated since version 5.8.0!
Use block_editor_rest_api_preload_paths instead in /sites/job-starter.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5691

Comment: have you got a backup, when it worked. as all databses are only files, something can go wrong. aomw providers so them automatocally. It is worth a  try

Comment: that error says only that you are mossing some tables, which can happen with a corrupt databse, so after checkeing the backups, you can try  to see if a recover is possible

Comment: hi - i have a backup - of course. But - i did not make a fresh installation. I will do this tomorrow. I guess that i have messed up the system with the big overhead of adding alltogether 5 languages. This is pretty much. I can imagine that this cause confilcts. 
I want to cut down this overhead -to a minimum - only runing this is one language _ english

Comment: many thanks - if i know which table to look for in detail then i can do this 

btw: have you seen the error messages on the site  https://www.job-starter.com in the header and the footer  - very interesting too 

Notice: is_feed was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /sites/www.job-starter.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5768